# Query Regarding Stream Provider in Flutter

Tags: google-cloud-firestore, flutter-provider

I'm currently trying out Stream Providers for noticing changes in Cloud Firestore Database and getting new data on change.

This is how I have created the Stream Provider :

```
child: StreamProvider.value(value: _firestoreAPI.getProjectsFromStream(_savedUser.user.name),child: PrimaryScene(toggleAnimation)),
```

As I am not able to call the provider from initstate ....Hence I'm calling is inside build :

```
_projectListSnapshotFromStream = Provider.of<QuerySnapshot>(context);
```

I have a doubt that if I rebuild the Widget containing the above call in its build function, will it charge me a read everytime I build that Widget because I called the provider? Or will it only charge a read when there is a change noticed in the database ?

Stream Definition :

```
Stream<QuerySnapshot> getProjectsFromStream(String username){
    return databaseReference.collection("Projects").where("Members",arrayContains: username).snapshots();
  }
```

Thankyou in advance for answering.

Answer (score 1):

will only count as read if you receive a new document from firestore

Comment: Is it because the "lazy build" property of the provider is set to true by default ?